# implement 'Group' cmdlet using .net cmdlets

Tags: .net, powershell, c#-4.0, powershell-cmdlet

I want to hide the `Group-Object` cmdlet behind a custom one so that the user doesnt get to know about the type of objects that the cmdlets return. So when I do :

```
$(Get-A;Get-B) | Group Result
```

where 'Result' is the type of objects that `Get-A` and `Get-B` output to pipeline and are the ones that I want to group together.

I am using powershell cmdlets in .NET to create the custom cmdlets.

Can the call be made to look like this? :

```
$(Get-A;Get-B) | Get-Combine
```

where `Get-Combine` does the exact same thing as Group does?

Comment: A function, of the same name, in scope will already trump a cmdlet. Just make one and try it.

Comment: Looks like an answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can do that using Proxy Functions.

You can find  articles about these functions written by [Shay Levy](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/03/01/proxy-functions-spice-up-your-powershell-core-cmdlets.aspx) or by [Don Jones](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/powershell-proxy-functions).

Answer (score 0):

As [JPBlanc mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33214016/3829407) you can use Proxy functions by extending the functionality of existing cmdlets. However I feel that what you are looking for is simpler. If you want to replace the functionality of a cmdlet the easiest way I can think of is just make your own of the same name.

The TechNet article [about_Command_Preferences](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848304.aspx) covers how this works.

> If you do not specify a path, Windows PowerShell uses the following
>            precedence order when it runs commands:
>
> 1. Alias
>
>    Function
>
>    Cmdlet
>
>    Native Windows commands

So you should just need to make your own function with the same name, as it appears in the list before cmdlet, and be done with it.

```
PS C:\Users\mcameron> function Get-ChildItem{"uh uh uh… I thought of that one, too, Better try again"}

PS C:\Users\mcameron> gci
uh uh uh… I thought of that one, too, Better try again
```

Comment: Trying again: `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Get-ChildItem` :D (i.e. it's useless as a security measure, but good enough for convenience; which is what the OP is after, I guess).

Comment: @Joey Exactly. I figured this was a measure of simplicity and not security through obscurity.